# Extracting predictor names when one predictor present in regression R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, coefficients

so I am currently running logistic regression and am attempting to extract summary information for individual predictors without including the intercept as follows:

```
zscores1<-summary(step1)$coefficients[-1,"z value"]
> zscores1
   i3        i2        i1 
0.5011802 2.7834229 2.0239975
```

Step1 is the model of interest here to provide context.  I ultimately want to extract just the included predictors:

```
allpredictorsincld<-rownames(summary(step1)$coefficients[-1,])
> allpredictorsincld
[1] "i3" "i2" "i1"
```

The issue I am having is if I only use one predictor I only get the information for that predictor, but the item number is dropped as follows:

```
> zscores1<-summary(step1)$coefficients[-1,"z value"]
> zscores1
[1] 5.644939
```

Where item 1 (i1) is the only item included as a predictor.  How can I make it so R gives me the value in addition to the item number?  So as to have something like this:

```
> zscores1
   i1
5.644939
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you show some of the data with `dput(head(zscores1))` perhaps?

Comment: use `summary(step1)$coefficients[-1,"z value",drop=FALSE]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution I discovered is converting the results to a data frame, then extracting the row names as follows:

```
> allpredsincld<-as.data.frame(summary(step1)$coefficients)
> allpredsincld
         Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -7.998346   1.216048 -6.577327 4.789808e-11
i1           3.928425   0.695920  5.644939 1.652402e-08
```

then:

```
> allpredsincld<-allpredsincld[-1,]
> allpredsincld
Estimate Std. Error  z value     Pr(>|z|)
i1 3.928425    0.69592 5.644939 1.652402e-08
```

and finally:

```
> rownames(allpredsincld)
[1] "i1"
```

Though Mr. Flick's solution is much quicker.